# Can I access to request object in django @register.assignment_tag

Tags: django

I need to access request object in a custom html tag **(Django ver 1.11)**. This tag is used in a top level html template which is used by almost all other templates in the proyect.

My code is this:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_color_style(context):
    request = context.get('request', None) #<---Here request object is None
    try:
        color = ehealth_models.CssSkin.objects.get(
            clinic=get_current_clinic(request)
        ).color_scheme
    except (ehealth_models.CssSkin.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
        color = 'defaultcolor'

    less_rule = os.path.join(
        settings.BASE_DIR,
        static('less/' + color + '.less')[1:]
    )
    color_values = dict()
    with open(less_rule, 'r') as f:
        file_str = f.read()
        file_str = file_str.replace('\n', '')
    for item in next(csv.reader([file_str], delimiter=';')):
        rule_item = next(csv.reader([item], delimiter=':'))
        if len(rule_item) == 2:
            color, color_value = None, None
            for value in rule_item:
                value = value.replace(' ', '')
                if value.startswith('@'):
                    color = value.replace('@', '').replace('-', '_')
                elif value.startswith('#'):
                    color_value = value
            color_values[color] = color_value
    return color_values
```

I use this tag in this way in my html:

```
{% get_color_style as color_style %}


<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

.....
```

It fails when I try to pass request var in html (even removing context from tag signature):

```
{% get_color_style request as color_style %}
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Try this, {% get_color_style request context %} and change your tag signatures to def get_color_style(request, context):

Comment: Thanks @danish_wani but it fails :(

Comment: you need to remove the very first statement of the tag definition and kindly try to print the request parameter and see is it passed correctly. This statement "request = context.get('request, None)" needs to go